# $\dim (U_1\cap U_2)\ge \dim U_1+\dim U_2-\dim V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm reading the excellent and incredible well-written book: [Algebraic Function Fields and Codes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540768777) by Henning Stichtenoth.

I don't remember this theorem in my linear algebra course, maybe this is a corollary of a known theorem written in linear algebra books.

[image]

I would like to know if there is a similar theorem of this one in linear algebra books or if there is a theorem which this fact is a corollary.

**Remark:**

I studied linear algebra by [Schaum's Outline of Linear Algebra, 5th Edition Seymour Lipschutz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071794565)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would a proof of the claim be a satisfactory answer? Nowhere in the question do you ask how to prove this, so I have to ask.

Comment: @GitGud yes, of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\dim(U_1+U_2)+\dim(U_1\cap U_2)=\dim U_1+\dim U_2
$$
An easy way to prove this is to use the 2nd isomorphism theorem:
$$
(U_1+U_2)/U_1\simeq U_2/(U_1\cap U_2)
$$

Since $U_1+U_2$ is at most the whole space $V$, you have your corollary. Its everywhere, in linear algebra and all sorts of subjects in algebra, and projective geometry...

Comment: What are $U$ and $V$? can you please just fix this part for future readers? Thank you!

Comment: @user42912 my bad. Corrected!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following chain of inequalities whose justifications I leave to you:
$$\begin{align} 
\dim(V)+\dim(U_1\cap U_2)&\ge \dim(U_1+U_2)+\dim(U_1\cap U_2)\\
&=(\dim(U_1)+\dim(U_2)-\dim(U_1\cap U_2))+\dim(U_2\cap U_2)\\
&=\dim(U_1)+\dim (U_2).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!